# Regex for matching whitespace between initials

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that removes whitespace between initials.

I figured out this expression:

```
(\w\.\s){2,}
```

Which will match only occurrences of 2 or more initials:

But I am stuck on how to match ONLY the whitespace within a group of 2 or more initials (except there should still be a space between last name and initials.)

When I remove the spaces, the expected result is that strings will change in the following way:

```
J. I. Howard --> J.I. Howard
J. Howard --> No change
J.I. Howard -> No change
J. O. B. Franklin --> J.O.B. Franklin
```

I think capture groups are probably involved somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: My only other issue is Excluding Mr. and Mrs. from the initial group.

For example:

```
Mr. L. P. Johnson --> Mr. L.P. Johnson
Mrs. C. Dalloway --> No change
```

Comment: are those examples the full text strings you are working with, or are they part of more context that has periods etc.? If it's the former, you can use lookahead, e.g. `\.\s+(?=.*\.)` if it's the latter.. that will be trickier. show examples

Comment: Seems to me that lookaround can solve that [`(?<=[A-Z]\.) (?=[A-Z]\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/puUyBs/1). If lookbehind is not supported maybe use a capture group in the replacement instead: [`\b([A-Z]\.) (?=[A-Z]\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/iicYPz/1)

Comment: @Crayon Violent Actually there is no further context. And your expression works.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, your expression works for me also... even excluding sequences of characters like Mr. and Mrs. Thank you both!

Comment: Are you wanting to transform the data? Then we need to know what app or language you're using.  If you're trying to select certain parts of a string, like select 'AC' out of 'ABC', then you can't do that with a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you can use either a lookbehind in combination with a lookahead:

```
(?<=[A-Z]\.) (?=[A-Z]\.)
```

Replace with empty string. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/puUyBs/1)

---

Or, capture preceding initial in a capture group and use a backreference in the replacement:

```
\b([A-Z]\.) (?=[A-Z]\.)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iicYPz/1).